# Variable into apache from block

Tags: apache-camel

For example I have from like this:

```
from("scheduler://a?scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=[some cron exp])
                    .to("activemq:queue:[some queue]").setHeader(Exchange.BREADCRUMB_ID, simple(simple(getContext().getUuidGenerator().generateUuid())))
                    .to("direct:saveSchedulerHistory")
```

I want to put this `simple(getContext().getUuidGenerator().generateUuid())`

into something like variable and put into saveSchedulerHistory (ofc I want to generate new always when scheduler start)

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]. You probably get downvoted for lack of attempts; see https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt You may also want to take the [tour] of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
.simple("camelContext.getUuidGenerator().generateUuid()")
```

Or use an inlined processor where you can do Java code.

```
.process(e -> e.getMessage().setHeader("xxx", ...."))
```